# Dual Primary OCFS2 DRBD encountered split-brain. Is recovery always going to be manual in this case?

Tags: linux, drbd, ocfs2

I've got two webservers which each have a disk attached. This disk is synced between them using `drbd` (2:8.3.13-1.1ubuntu1) in 'dual-primary' mode, and over the top of this I run `ocfs2` (1.6.4-1ubuntu1) as a cluster filesystem. The nodes communicate on a private network `192.168.3.0/24`. For the most part, this is stable, and works well.

Last night, there appeared to have been a network outage. This resulted in a split-brain scenario where node01 was left in `Standalone` and `Primary`, while node02 was left in `WFConnection` and `primary`. Recovery was a manual process this morning of diffing the two filesystems, deciding that node01 should be authoritative, putting node02 into secondary and then issuing `drbdadm connect` commands on each node. Remounting the filesystem after this and we're back up and running.

My question is: Is this type of outage always going to require a manual resolution? Or are there ways in which this process can be automated? My understanding was that drbd should try to be intelligent in the event of a split brain about working out which node should become primary and secondary. It seems that in this case, a simple network outage left both in primary, which my config just says 'disconnect'. Looking at the logs, what I find interesting is the fact that they both seemed to agree that `node02` should be the SyncSource, and yet when looking at the rsync log, it's actually `node01` that has the most recent changes. Also interesting is the line on `node01` stating 'I shall become SyncTarget, but I am primary!'. To me, it looks like drbd tried to resolve this, but failed for some reason.

Is there a better way of doing this?

The config for `r0` is this:

```
resource r0 {
    meta-disk internal;
    device /dev/drbd0;
    disk /dev/xvda2;

    syncer { rate 1000M; }
    net {
        #We're running ocfs2, so two primaries desirable.
        allow-two-primaries;

        after-sb-0pri discard-zero-changes;
        after-sb-1pri discard-secondary;
        after-sb-2pri disconnect;

    }
    handlers{
        before-resync-target "/sbin/drbdsetup $DRBD_MINOR secondary";

        split-brain "/usr/lib/drbd/notify-split-brain.sh root";
    }
    startup { become-primary-on both; }

    on node02 { address 192.168.3.8:7789; }
    on node01 { address 192.168.3.1:7789; }
}
```

I've also put the `kern.log` files on pastebin:

Node01: http://pastebin.com/gi1HPtut

Node02: http://pastebin.com/4XSCDQdC

Comment: Hum. Is there a specific reason you are not using quorum so the split-brain scenario could be effectively prevented instead of dealing with it after the fact?

Comment: Not sure I follow - the documentation I've been referencing regarding doing this sort of dual-primary setup makes no mention of using a quorum for drbd. I can see how a third-node quorum would help some split-brain scenarios, but initially can't see where/how this would be configured with drbd.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you already choose the best SB-policy for DRBD. So in your case there had to be changes on the same part of the filesystem (i.e. DRBD-block) on BOTH sides.

So in that case - yes - you have to resolve that manually.

The question that arises to me is **why did these concurrent accesses happen**?

You should investigate into that direction. If network is down there should be no access at one side, so "discard zero changes" should help - but it did not.

Apart from that your should prevent split brains by having two or more INDEPENDENT network connections. I always use three of them on my clusters.